# How to identify if an error crashes the app in Flutter with Sentry

Tags: flutter, crash, sentry

I'm tracking all my app crashes [with Sentry](https://pub.dev/packages/sentry_flutter) and all errors are tracked successfully, but I still haven't found a way to identify if the error reported by Sentry is a common error or is crashing the app.

have someone found a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Flutter apps don't crash that easily, since the unhandled callback swallows the exception.
A Flutter app may crash tho if the crash happened in the Native layer, a (C, C++) code on Android or iOS), if that happens, you will see an "Unhandled" label on Sentry issues.
If you want to filter all unhandled events on Flutter, You may be interested in this issue https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dart/issues/456

Answer (score 0):

In the Senter you can specify the level of errors to be sent.
I suggest you read this part of the document Sentery for flutter.

Please visit this url  (diagnosticLevel).
[Sentry Basic Options](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/flutter/configuration/options/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion. I can confirm that I have this implementation running (Sentry logs) and I have read de documentation. 
What I'm asking for (the documentation is not clear) is to identify if an error is just an error or if this error is crashing the app. That's what I'm asking/looking for

Comment: `diagnosticlevel` is something else, it is a debug level for the SDK itself.